# Difference between KStream mapValues and transformValues

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

Referring to their javadoc, `KStream.transformValues` demands additional storeName parameter and thus stateful, also with `transformValues` method we can make use of `ProccessorContext` and `Punctuator`s.

Is there a special concrete case for which, I should prefer `transformValues` over `mapValues`?

Comment: Note, that the `stateStore` parameter is optional.

Comment: Rule of thumb: stick with simple `mapValues()` if you can, as it's less code to write. But it would be safe to always use `transformValues()` instead; it's just unnecessarily complex if you don't need to have a store, access record metadata, or use punctuations.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your use case. If you want to implement a custom (value)transformer with supplier and aiming more towards using the [PAPI](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html) maybe you should go for the transform or transformValues. If you need the context for e.g. accessing full records with headers, partition/offset information you might want to use the PAPI. This is quite often the case if you want more control over your stream topology and underlying details. For "simple" transformations map/mapValues might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If your operation is stateful and you are doing some aggregation across multiple records use `transformValues`.

Otherwise use `mapValues`.